How to filter words using regular expression in BigQuery table? I'm getting error trying with SQL queries
I am using Google BigQuery table, into which I am inserting a few rows to submit table but for one of the columns [manfacturing_output] few categories are coming with sentence so I tried to remove the words which are not needed through regular expression but am unable to resolve issue

  import os
  import json
 from deepdiff import DeepDiff  # You might need to install 
this package

Paths to the folders
actual_json_folder = 'path_to_actual_json_folder'
comparison_json_folder = 'path_to_comparison_json_folder'
output_folder = 'path_to_output_folder'

# Ensure the output folder exists
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

def load_json(filepath):
  with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    return json.load(file)

def compare_json_files(actual_file, comparison_file, output_file):
  actual_data = load_json(actual_file)
  comparison_data = load_json(comparison_file)

  diff = DeepDiff(actual_data, comparison_data, ignore_order=True).to_dict()

  with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(diff, file, indent=4)

def main():
   actual_files = os.listdir(actual_json_folder)
   comparison_files = os.listdir(comparison_json_folder)

  # Process each file
   for filename in actual_files:
       if filename in comparison_files:
        actual_file = os.path.join(actual_json_folder, filename)
        comparison_file = os.path.join(comparison_json_folder, filename)
        output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)

        compare_json_files(actual_file, comparison_file, output_file)
        print(f"Differences for {filename} stored in {output_file}")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()




Only for bigquery you are looking out? or sql specific?

Yes! i have to write in google big query

What about this?
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    "The category is \"Clamp Break\"." AS manfacturing_output
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "Turner Usability" AS manfacturing_output
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "The category for the response is \"Clamp Break\"." AS manfacturing_output
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "The category for this response is \"Turner Usability\"." AS manfacturing_output
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "Clamp Break" AS manfacturing_output
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "The category is \"Machine & Errors\"." AS manfacturing_output
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "The category for the response is \"Turner Usability\"." AS manfacturing_output )
SELECT
  manfacturing_output,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(manfacturing_output, r'\"') THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(manfacturing_output, r'\"(.*?)\"' )
  ELSE
  manfacturing_output
END
  AS output
FROM
  data


Not working above logic

So, your sample is wrong. Share a sample table in BigQuery with allUsers, and share the link to let us explore it and find the correct syntax

I have updated multiple queries above those are the ones I tried & the column name is manfacturing_output ..
